# Python3 tkinter multiple windows and widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, ttk

```
#Home Window
class Window1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

#Menu Bar Widgets
#<---------------------------------------------------->
    #Port Scanner Window Code
    def portscanner(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)


    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Multipurpose Security Tool")

        menubar = Menu(self.parent) 
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)


    #Capture Menu Code
    #<----------------------------------------------------->
        captureMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,)

        #Submenu Send Packet
        #<----------------------------------------------------->
        submenu = Menu(captureMenu, tearoff=0)
        submenu.add_command(label="Send TCP Packet")
        submenu.add_command(label="Send UDP Packet")
        captureMenu.add_cascade(label="Send Packet", menu=submenu, underline=0)
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        #<----------------------------------------------------->
        #Regular Menu Widgets under Capture
        captureMenu.add_command(label="TCP Packet Analyzer")
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="UDP Packet Analyzer")
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="Port Scanner",command=self.portscanner)
        captureMenu.add_separator()
        captureMenu.add_command(label="Whois Lookup")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Capture", menu=captureMenu)
    #<----------------------------------------------------->

    def showMenu(self, e):
        self.menu.post(e.x_root, e.y_root)

    #Exit Code on MenuBar
    def onExit(self):
        quitquestion = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Quit","Are you sure you want to quit?")
        if quitquestion == "yes":
            self.quit()

    #New Code on MenuBar
    def new(self):
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)



#Port Scanner
class Window2(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI2()
```

This is the Frame where I am trying to put widgets on but it does nothing when I run it. I am using PyCharm as my editor. Trying to make widgets so user can interact with it. I am wanting to make an input box and a button that has text "run". It does not show anything in the debugger.

```
   def initUI2(self):
       self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
       self.parent.title("Port Scanner")
       self.parent.geometry("500x300+400+200")
       self.runbutton = Button(self,text="Run")
       self.runbutton.pack()



#Windows Settings
def main():
#<----------------------------------------------------->
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x300+400+100")
    app = Window1(root)
    #Page 1 and Page 2 Tab
    root.mainloop()
#<----------------------------------------------------->

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not going to run your code and guess what the problem is. What is your question?

Comment: you forgot to call `.pack()` on one of the widgets you created. (self.app)

Comment: I tried self.app.pack() and it gave me an error. I also tried self.frame.pack() and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `portscanner()` method use `pack()` to make `self.app` visible on the screen.

```
def portscanner(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = Window2(self.newWindow)
    self.app.pack()
```

Comment: self.pack() worked

Answer (score 0):

The entire contents of your GUI are inside the window `app`. However, you never put `app` on the screen using pack, place, or grid, so it remains invisible.

Since `app` appears to be the only widget in the root window, you probably want to add this code right before calling `mainloop`:

```
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```